# Translating: "Christ Jesus Ultimate King & Ruler for All Time"

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

I have considered that this may be stated: "*Christī Regēns*", emphasising with a capital R and being pronounced actively ruling. Is this sufficient to state?

I wonder that is is not more like, "*Christi Cesar Regens*" though I have not all of the correct letter inflexions.

It must be careful, if correct, to pronounce Christ as Cesar and not pronounce Cesar as Christ.

Addendum: I concede pronouncing Christ as Cesar is not the answer to what I wish to translate. Is it indeed that "*Christī Regēns*" is sufficient?

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not quite clear on what you wish to express.  There is a possible conflict here with associating "Caesar"/"Cesar" with Christ, seeing that "Caesar" is an emblem of secular power, and Christ is definitely is not.  Having said that, I acknowledge that later Roman times, both "Augustus" and "Caesar" came to be as terms for the emperors and their backups in the new, Christian, Roman empire.  I do think you need to explain more thoroughly what you're looking for,

Comment: @varro The question title is not clear? Is it not that Caesar/Cesar is the Latin term for ultimate ruler?

Comment: No.  In later times, the title of "Augustus" was higher than the title of "Caesar".  In Byzantine times, the ultimate power was in the hand of the Βασιλεύς, the "emperor" (a title fraught will all sorts of connotations).

Comment: @Willtech Also consider that the Bible uses Caesar exclusively for secular rulers: hence "render unto Caesar that which is Caesar's, and render unto God that which is God's"

Comment: So, a difficult question. Another question, would Christ put His picture on money? Then is "Christī Regēns" sufficient?

Comment: For "Caesar" see this: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/german-kaiser-russian-tsar-arabic-qay%E1%B9%A3ar.3163959/

Comment: Your _Christī Regēns_ is inconsistent as to inflection. The first word is genitive (presumably not nominative plural!) the second nominative. _Christus Regēns_ for the nominative.

Comment: I tagged this [tag:ecclesiastical-latin], assuming you are ok with this, considering the religious tone of the sentence. Pleas feel free to change it back, or just ask me to undo it.

Comment: @ColinFine I fully accept Latin seems difficult to master. So then, if I understand (from another question) that would still make "Es certus facere tē discipulum Christī Regēns." to be correct?

Comment: @Willtech: nope. "Christī" is genitive ("of the Christ"). "Regēns" is nominative, so the only thing it could possible refer to in the sentence is the (unspoken) subject "you" So it means "Be sure to make yourself a disciple of the Christ, O ruling one1". I don't think that's what you meant. Try "Christī Regēntis" "of the ruling Christ".

Comment: @ColinFine I will take you on your word.

Comment: @ColinFine How do you take to read "Es certus facere tē discipulum Christī Regēntis Rēgis."

Comment: That works,, as far as the last few words go, and it is grammatical. What I don't know is whether "es certus facere" actually _means_ "be sure to make". That is certainly a literal translation, but I have no idea whether or not the **idiom** "be sure/certain to" translates directly into Latin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a short phrase, I'd go for something simple like **[Iesus] Chistus Rex**. It says little more or less than *Christ [is the] King*. It stands alone as a title or as a copulative sentence, since in Latin the verb *to be* can be easily omitted. In the latter, there is little doubt that you are saying that Christ is king and not the other way around.

If you want to translate the whole thing, I see two approaches: the literal one—a somewhat word-by-word, yet grammatical translation—and the liturgical one—building a mosaic from attested titles and liturgical ways of saying.

---

1. As for the literal approach, I had some trouble with the words *ultimate* and the difference between *ruler* and *king*.

   [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aultimate) gives two meanings for *ultimate*: i) basically a synonym of *last/final* and ii) *best/supreme*. I'll go for the second one. But feel free to ask for the eschatological version.

   For *king* I'll go with the obvious alternative, **rex**. For ruler, I'll use *[Dominus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddominus)*. It is a common word with a wide meaning. In a religious context, its primary meaning is *Lord*, but it also means *ruler*. Please make me know if you want to convey a specific contrast with *king* or make it more explicit that you mean *ruler* and not *lord* (in this case, an alternative could be the less frequent **dominator**).

   The translation could therefore be:

   > **Christus Iesus Rex Optimus et Dominus in omni tempore**

---

2. As for the liturgial approach I think of two opposing ideas.

   *For ever* in liturgy is almost always a variant of *for centuries of centuries*: **[per/in] + [saeculum saeculi/[omnia] saecula [saeculorum]]**. To speak about titles of Jesus, I think this makes more sense.

   Christ has been called *the King* from old. Prominently, the full name of the feast day of Christ the King includes *of all things* (or *of the universe*) in its name. Concretely, *Dominus Noster Iesus Christus Universorum Rex* (note it includes both **Dominus** and **Rex**). If you are willing to accept *of all things* instead of *ultimate* to stick to liturgy, this is the way to go. In this case, the translation could be:

   > **Christus Iesus Universorum Rex et Dominus per saecula**

   The other option is to base the translation in the hymn *[Christus Vincit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laudes_Regi%C3%A6)*. It is a prominent prayer that in the refrain makes reference to Christ as King stressing different aspects of his triumph in Resurrection. The relevant part is:

   > Christus vincit, Christus regnat, Christus imperat / *Christ conquers, Christ reigns, Christ commands*

   Note that using this in the mosaic, the translation becomes arguably freer, since the offices (nouns) are changed by actions (verbs).

   > **Christus Iesus regnat atque imperat per [omnia] saecula saeculorum**

---

Notes:

- **et** and **atque** are [two different ways](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/what-is-the-difference-between-ac-or-atque-and-et) of saying *and*.
- *Rex optimus et Dominus* [can mean](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-gender-should-a-predicate-adjective-be-to-agree-with-a-series-of-things-wit) that ultimate applies to both king and ruler.
- **Chistus Iesus** and **Iesus Christus** are equivalent. I chose the former to stick to your word order in English, but this could be misleading if used as a general rule. It doesn't need to be that way.
- My personal choice would be the second one, *Christus Iesus Universorum Rex...*

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your work here and may yet add a couple of comments. I accept that Lord is a much more well-mannered situation seemingly befitting of Christ than DOMINATOR gives us by common understanding.